# Using smsj: Sending SMS of Base64 encoded string

Tags: java, html, sms-gateway

I've got a Java String that is Base64 encoded. I need to send that Java String via SMS to another SMS application on a GSM mobile phone that expects the String to be delivered in Basse64 encoding format. I am using Clickatell HTTP API with smsj java library as follows:

```
public void SendBinarySMSMessage(String toPhone, String cTxt, String toPort, String fromPhone) throws Exception {
// Note that 'cTxt' is Base64 encoded string 
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("smsj.clickatell.username", "xxxxxxx");
    props.setProperty("smsj.clickatell.password","yyyyy");
    props.setProperty("smsj.clickatell.apiid","zzzzzzz");
    // Now load the clickatell transport
    SmsTransport transport = SmsTransportManager.getTransport("org.marre.sms.transport.clickatell.ClickatellTransport", props);
    // Connect to clickatell
    transport.connect();
    // Create and send the sms message
    int dstPort = Integer.parseInt(toPort);
    int srcPort = Integer.parseInt(toPort);
    SmsPortAddressedTextMessage textMessage = new SmsPortAddressedTextMessage(dstPort,srcPort,cTxt);
    transport.send(textMessage,new SmsAddress(toPhone),new SmsAddress(fromPhone));
    // Disconnect from clickatell
    transport.disconnect();
}
```

Each time I try to send the mesage, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE:   org.marre.sms.SmsException: Clickatell API cannot send 7 bit encoded messages with UDH
at org.marre.sms.transport.clickatell.ClickatellTransport.buildSendRequest(ClickatellTransport.java:385)
```

Here is the value of cTXT string I am tryng to send: "56pRfQSuddMbjOc8ibMyYKkmLTQ8AZpAz3sT+5JrGDw="

How do I fix this problem?

Thank you.